# python mkdir maakedirs create directory with name like existing file

Tags: python, windows, mkdir, create-directory

I want to create a directory with name like existing file. In this case i have file named test and I want to create directory with the same name. On Linux i can use just `os.system("mkdir " + dir_name)` but on windows it dosn't work. So I tried `os.mkdir` and `os.makedirs` like below:

```
import os

def my_function():
    path = input("Enter dir name or full path.")
    try:   
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)
```

Both `os.mkdir` and `os.makedirs` give me an error:

> [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'test'

First question, why cannot create a file? It's mkdir. I'm tring to create directory not a file.
Second question: the file and directory with the same name can coexists. Why I can't create it. How I can make it in way that will run on Win and Linux.

Comment: You can't create a directory and a file with the same name in a given directory in either Linux or Windows. Maybe on Linux you're creating it in a different directory than you think, or with different casing. Windows file systems are case insensitive, so "dirname" is the same as "dIrNaMe".

Comment: Ok. Right I can do that only on Linux. On Windows it dosn't work. Thanks

Comment: You cannot have both a file and a directory named `./test/test` *on Linux*. That doesn't work on any OS that I've used.